# Sites that create personalized workout routine based on target weight?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, weight-gain

Are there sites (free or otherwise) that will create a workout routine based on what your target goal is?

For example, my girlfriend (who's heavyset and does weights) measures 5'8" and weighs about 170. She told me she wants to gain healthy weight and weigh between 190-200 pounds. She currently goes to the gym and has a normal fat percentage.

What site can assign a good routine (exercise and diet, I guess) that will allow her to reach that target weight? Basically, it would be a site where she inputs all her current data (height, weight, fat %, etc) and with that specific information, assign a real routine.

Thanks.

Comment: You gain weight through eating more, not exercising more. Calories In > Calories Out

Comment: So you're saying to just eat and not go to the gym?

Comment: You don't gain healthy weight by not exercising.

Comment: To clarify: To gain weight: Calories In > Calories Out. What form that weight takes (muscle/fat) depends entirely on the exercise content and the dietary macro-nutritional profile.

Comment: I would suggest a goal of reaching a certain body fat percentage rather than a random number for total body weight.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there sites (free or otherwise) that will create a workout routine based on what your target goal is?

Yes, hundreds if not thousands, simple google search of 'create workout routine online'.

> What site can assign a good routine

Bottom line: NONE!

Everyone is different so a good routine is realized through trial and error, a good diet is easier though, humans mainly need the same things, just more or less of a particular nutrient!

Now; you **MAY** luck out and though some random miraculous anomaly, a site could describe the perfect plan. But I wouldn't count on it.

The best workout/diet plans are created by knowing your body, seeing what is the most effective and slowly expanding from there. That is why trainers usually try different things to see which are the most suited for that particular person's body.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you an online or personal trainer.

I once had an online coach as well. I got a more or less personalized nutrition plan, a new workout routine each week and skype sessions to talk about slight modifications in order to reach my specific goal.

There were other people doing the more or less same workouts and there has always been a community to power you (it was a facebook group).

By now, approx. 4 years have passed since I had this course and I still like the plans I got.